# Docker + Sveltekit, cant access localhost:3000

Tags: docker, svelte, sveltekit

After building I start the image and see in the terminal:

```
*Executing task: docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000/tcp bamdock:latest 
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000*
```

However when trying to reach http://localhost:3000/ in browser I see:

```
*The connection was reset*

*The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.*
```

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:19 as builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY prisma ./prisma/

COPY .env ./

RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:19-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

My first time trying to get Docker working ...

Comment: Using different 'OS' versions for building and running *can* cause issues, so try using `node:19-alpine3.16` for building as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply ... I tried node:18-alpine and node:19-alpine for both but still same problem.